# Removing ZM From Geometry Column Polygon Using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

Using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop, I have some Shapefiles which I have no idea why their Geometry column (shape) contain ZM! now I need to remove all those `ZM` and get a clean polygon instead.

I thought I can use the `FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion()` but not sure how to `disabled` both `Output has Z Values` and `Output has M Values` through following ArcPy

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/data"

# Set local variables
inFeature = ["climate.shp"]
outLocation = "C:/output"

arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(inFeatures, outLocation)
```

Comment: Set environment variable Z and M to disabled

Comment: Thanks FelixIP, this is exactly my questing! how can I do it?  I didn't find any thing on ArcGIS Online Help, I know this is doable trough ArcToolbox but how in ArcPy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"   
arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"
```

Resources can be found here [Z](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001w00000006000000) and [M](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Output_has_M_values/001w00000007000000/)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the only way you can find out which environment settings a tool honors is to look at the Help file for a particular tool. There is a section on every tools help page called Environment listing which ones it honors.